# Unwrapping the Functions without parameters in scala with Futures

Tags: scala, functional-programming, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to create a transformation chain to define possible transformations for given functions:

```
type Transformation[T] = T => Future[T]

def transformationChain[T](chain: Seq[Transformation[T]]): Transformation[T] = {
}


val t1: Transformation[Int] = t => Future.successful(t + t)
val t2: Transformation[Int] = _ => Future.failed(new NoSuchElementException)
val t3: Transformation[Int] = t =>
    if (t > 2) Future.successful(t * t)
    else Future.failed(new NoSuchElementException)

val tc = transformationChain(Seq(t1, t2, t2, t3))
val tc2 = transformationChain(Seq(t2, t2, t2))
val tc3 = transformationChain(Seq(t2, t3, t1))

println(Await.result(tc(2), 5.seconds))  // 16
println(Await.result(tc2(2), 5.seconds)) // throw NoSuchElementException
println(Await.result(tc3(2), 5.seconds)) // 4
```

The problem is that I don't understand how to unwrap these functions in "transformationChain" method to send the result to every next function in the chain by calling them in the loop or recursively.

Comment: Why shouldn't they all return `Future.failed(NoSuchElementException)` given the definition of `t2`?

Comment: If all the functions return NoSuchElementException without any numeric result, the result of transformationChain should return Transformation[Int] = _ => Future.failed(new NoSuchElementException)
In other cases it should return some numeric result without exceptions.

Comment: So in the other cases, it should "ignore" all the transformations that threw the `NoSuchElementException` and keep passing the "previous result" onto the next one?

Comment: exactly like that

Comment: Doesn't just `reduce` with `flatMap` should do the job?

Comment: Maybe... It can work if it's Futures, not the transformations. But it's only my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

What you're described as **Transformation** (so function of **A => F[B]**) is called often Kleisli arrows.

[Cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/kleisli.html) library has a data type, that makes operation on these kinds of functions easier. For example, it has a method **andThen** which allows the composition of these functions:

```
import cats.data.Kleisli
import cats.implicits._

val t1: Transformation[Int] = t => Future.successful(t + t)
val t2: Transformation[Int] = _ => Future.failed(new NoSuchElementException)

Kleisli(t1).andThen(Kleisli(t2))
```

The only problem is, that one of your transformations could return the failed future, which would short-circuit the whole chain. We can fix it with **recoverWith**.

So finally **transformationChain** could look like:

```
def transformationChain[T](chain: Seq[Transformation[T]]): Transformation[T] =
    t =>
      chain
         //wrap the function in Kleisli and then use replace failed futures with succeeded
         //future, that are passing value over
        .map(Kleisli(_).recoverWith {
          case _ => Kleisli(x => Future.successful(x))
        })
        .reduce(_ andThen _) //combine all elements with andThen
        .apply(t)
```

It works fine for case 1 and 3 but fails for case 2 since it will just return passed value.

```
println(Await.result(tc(2), 5.seconds)) // 16
println(Await.result(tc3(2), 5.seconds)) // 4
println(Await.result(tc2(2), 5.seconds)) // 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import scala.concurrent.{ ExecutionContext, Future }
import scala.util.Try

import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object Transformations {
  type Transformation[T] = T => Future[T]

  private object DummyException extends Exception
  private val notReallyAFailedFuture: Future[Throwable] = Future.failed(DummyException)

  def transformationChain[T](chain: Seq[Transformation[T]])(implicit ectx: ExecutionContext): Transformation[T] = t =>
    if (chain.nonEmpty) {
      val initialFut = Future.successful(t)
      // resultFut will succeed if any of the transformations in the chain succeeded
      // lastFailure will fail if all of the transformations succeeded, otherwise it has the last failure
      val (resultFut: Future[T], lastFailure: Future[Throwable]) =
        chain.foldLeft((Future.failed[T](DummyException), notReallyAFailedFuture)) { (acc, v) =>
          val thisResult = acc._1.recoverWith {
            case _ => initialFut
          }.flatMap(v)
          val lastFailure = thisResult.failed.recoverWith { case _ => acc._2 }
          (thisResult.recoverWith { case _ => acc._1 }, lastFailure)
        }
      resultFut.recoverWith {
        case _ =>
          lastFailure.flatMap(Future.failed)
      }
    } else Future.successful(t)   // What to do with an empty chain is unspecified

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import scala.concurrent.Await
    import scala.concurrent.duration._

    val t1: Transformation[Int] = t => Future.successful(t + t)
    val t2: Transformation[Int] = _ => Future.failed(new NoSuchElementException)
    val t3: Transformation[Int] = t =>
      if (t > 2) Future.successful(t * t)
      else Future.failed(new NoSuchElementException)

    val tc1 = transformationChain(Seq(t1, t2, t2, t3))
    val tc2 = transformationChain(Seq(t2, t2, t2))
    val tc3 = transformationChain(Seq(t2, t3, t1))

    println(Try(Await.result(tc1(2), 5.seconds)))
    println(Try(Await.result(tc2(2), 5.seconds)))
    println(Try(Await.result(tc3(2), 5.seconds)))
  }
}
```

This implementation assumes that:

- If multiple transformations fail, return the last failure
- If the chain is empty, assume an identity transformation

`transformationChain` does now require an implicit `ExecutionContext` for scheduling the "glue" functions between the transformation futures.  In Scala 2.13+, the `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.parasitic` context is actually a pretty good choice for executing these quick transformations (and is useful for basically nothing else).

In order to get all the `println`s to execute, I've wrapped the `Await.result`s in `Try`.

In the interest of brevity, there's some use of a failed `Future` to represent absence of a result.